# In C++, where the info about type is stored and how type safety check is performed?

Tags: c++, type-safety

Type safety is a big thing in C++. Variables of different types which don't support implicit conversions can not be set to be equal. 
How this safety check is performed? 
In addition to the variable itself, is there some information about type stored for that variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable itself doesn't contain any information about what it contains. Instead C++ uses its compile step to perform a wide array of verification steps to ensure that everything will work correctly during run time.

Put simply if I have the following function:

```
double convert(int32_t num)
{
    return static_cast<double>(num);
}
```

It compiles into a procedure which takes its one and only parameter and performs a 32-bit integer to 64-bit floating point conversion. If you gave it a 32-bit floating point number it would do the incorrect thing.

However the type system ensures that anyone who calls `convert` supplies a 32-bit integer (note the compiler may insert a conversion on your behalf in some cases, but the function only ever sees a 32-bit integer) and thus there is no need for a run-time check that what you supplied is actually a 32-bit integer.

The type system does exist at compile time of course and is tracked quite carefully. Take the following example:

```
int32_t x = 12;
double y = convert(x);
```

The compilers view of this includes that `x` is an `int32_t`, `convert` takes a `int32_t` and returns a `double` and `y` is a `double`. Since those all line up no conversion is necessary and it compiles successfully. In contrast:

```
char* x = "12";
double y = convert(x);
```

Doesn't compile because `char *` is not the same (and is not convertible) to `int32_t`.

Comment: So it is checked by the compiler, is this what it means when saying "C++ is a statically typed language"?

Comment: @Allanqunzi: Yes until you get really deep into the meaning of statically typed. Technically the two concepts we are talking about don't quite overlap but pretty much every implementation does.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is designed as a *compiled* language. Which means that whatever checks are required by the language specification are performed at compilation time by the compiler. Everything that is necessary for such checks is stored by the compiler in compiler's inner data structures. These data structures exists only during compilation.

Once the C++ code is successfully compiled into executable code, all checks are done. Nothing is stored anymore. Nothing is checked anymore.

In other words, type-safety checks in C++ language are *static*.

The only exception from this principle is the functionality of `dynamic_cast`, which can perform certain run-time (dynamic) type checks. For that storing some run-time type information (RTTI) is indeed necessary. The same data is used for run-time type identification through `typeid`. But this is a separate topic, which does not really override the fact that general type checking in C++ is *static* in nature.